# Additional white space after first line in paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with formatting a paragraph in HTML.  My goal was to indent the first line in each paragraph, but the very first line in each paragraph is being indented and the very first line is adding extra white space or carriage return before the second sentence.  What is the best way to format a paragraph without adding the extra white space?

My inline CSS is the following code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    p { text-indent: 12px; margin: 0%; margin-top: 0%; margin-bottom: 0% }
</style>
```

The result looks like this:

```
       The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy log.  The quick brown fox jumped 

over the lazy log.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy log.  The quick 
brown fox jumped over the lazy log.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy 
log.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy log.  The quick brown fox jumped 
over the lazy log.
```

Comment: Please include your HTML or a link to your site. Cheers

Comment: Your CSS is proper.It will indent only the first line of your all paragraphs. Check whether you have provided some space between two sentences or some other styles.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the CSS styling you gave:

[image]

Try it: https://refork.codicode.com/xd5b

Comment: the OP asks not about indentation